# Joomla 4 AJAX request and Cyrillic characters

Tags: joomla-4.x, ajax

There is an input field of type text -  **pib_input**
I am sending to the Ajax server

```
    let pib_input = $('#pib_input').val();
    console.log(pib_input);
    $.ajax({
        data: { [token]: "1", task: "AjaxSendEmail", tmpl: "component",format: "raw",pib_input: pib_input},
        success: function(responce) {
            alert(responce);
        },
        error: function(responce) {
            alert(responce);
        },
    });
```

The following is sent to the server

```
http://127.0.0.1/j4/index.php?option=com_tsnap&view=groups_list&Itemid=325&2cf3da9ecdc730484a55452a93f49079=1&task=AjaxSendEmail&tmpl=component&format=raw&pib_input=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82
```

On the server

```
$app = Factory::getApplication();


$input = $app->input;
$pib_input = $input->get('pib_input');
$pib_input1 = urldecode($app->input->get('pib_input'));
$pib_input2 = json_decode($app->input->get('pib_input'));
$pib_input3 = html_entity_decode($app->input->get('pib_input'));
$pib_input4 = htmlspecialchars_decode($app->input->get('pib_input'));

$file = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_tsnap/result.txt';
file_put_contents($file, 'pib_input:'.$pib_input.PHP_EOL.'pib_input1:'.$pib_input1.PHP_EOL.'pib_input2:'.$pib_input2.PHP_EOL.'pib_input3:'.$pib_input3);
```

File contents

```
pib_input:
pib_input1:
pib_input2:
pib_input3:
```

If eplace

```
let pib_input = encodeURI($('#pib_input').val());
```

File contents

```
pib_input:D09FD180D0B8D0B2D196D182
pib_input1:D09FD180D0B8D0B2D196D182
pib_input2:
pib_input3:D09FD180D0B8D0B2D196D182
```

How do I transfer and process Cyrillic characters correctly?
The data will be used to send an email

```
Factory::getMailer()->sendMail
```

Thank you.